# Is it possible to pin the container to a remote machine instead of a new container instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, docker-swarm

I am reading up on docker, ECS tools. 
There are many remote physical hosts- hostA, hostB, hostC .....
We want to use docker/ECS to manage our software deployment process which right now is very manual.

I understand the basics of docker but I can't get my head around how to actually deploy code changes to a remote machine using docker or even to execute a simple command on the remote machine.

How can I run the tasks inside the remote machine instead of a container instance? or if it has to be a container instance, I make the code changes in the container, how will the remote machine get the updates? is this even possible? I hope I make sense.

All the examples I see online are to deploy an application on an EC2 instance or something like that. What I need is to deploy or run commands on an already existing physical machine. Any other better ways to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question, but what I think might be helpful is to treat containers as disposable. They do a single task then you throw them away.  If you want to do something else you create a new container.

Making changes is just killing off old containers and starting new ones in their place.  So you don't actually change code in a container, you would just start running a new one with the new code.